# ¿Cómo crear y usar archivos de script de recursos en C?

Tags: c, winapi

Tengo una duda respecto a los archivos de script de recursos o *resource script* (.rc) en C para WinAPI. Recién me introduzco al WinAPI y viendo referencias en Internet veo este código para implementar menús:

```
#include <windows.h>
#define IDC_STATIC -1

100 ICON "ProgIcon.ico"

10 MENU
{               // or BEGIN
 POPUP "&File"
 {
  MENUITEM "&Exit",IDCANCEL
 }
}               // or END
```

y no entiendo la línea de `100 MENU` ¿por qué un número antes de la palabra? He buscado más información sobre estos archivos y solo he encontrado otros ejemplos para agregar menús:

```
IDM_MY_MENU MENU DISCARDABLE
BEGIN
   POPUP "File"
   BEGIN
       MENUITEM "Open", IDC_FILE_OPEN
       MENUITEM "Save", IDC_FILE_SAVE
       MENUITEM "Close", IDC_FILE_CLOSE
   END
   POPUP "Edit"
   BEGIN
       MENUITEM "Cut", IDC_EDIT_CUT
       MENUITEM "Copy", IDC_EDIT_COPY
       MENUITEM "Paste", IDC_EDIT_PASTE
   END
   POPUP "View"
   BEGIN
       POPUP "Toolbars"
       BEGIN
           MENUITEM "Standard", IDC_VIEW_STANDARD
           MENUITEM "Custom", IDC_VIEW_CUSTOM
       END
   END
   MENUITEM "Help", IDC_HELP
 END
```

¿Se supone que `ID_MY_MENU` puede ser cualquier número? Y las definiciones:

```
 //resource.h
 #define IDC_FILE_OPEN       200
 #define IDC_FILE_SAVE       201
 #define IDC_FILE_CLOSE      202
 #define IDC_EDIT_COPY       203
 #define IDC_EDIT_CUT        204
 #define IDC_EDIT_PASTE      205
 #define IDC_VIEW_STANDARD   206
 #define IDC_VIEW_CUSTOM     207
 #define IDC_HELP            208
```

Pero lo que no entiendo es dónde los creo, cómo los compilo o cómo hago que los lea mi archivo fuente, y si los identificadores definidios con `#define` pueden ser cualquier número  o no.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿por qué un número antes de la palabra?

Atendiendo a la [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381025(v=vs.85).aspx) de la MSDN, la sintaxis para los menús es la siguiente:

```
menuID MENU  [optional-statements]  {item-definitions ... }
```

donde `menuID` debe ser un identificador numérico único.

> ¿Se supone que ID_MY_MENU puede ser cualquier número?

Sí. El único requisito es que no puedes repetir identificador en tu aplicación.

Esos identificadores los tienes que proporcionar tu porque así puedes identificar con qué elemento del menú está interactuando el usuario... si los identificadores te los facilitase la api de windows no podrías hacerlo.

Imagina, por ejemplo, que la API te dice que el usuario ha hecho click en el menú con identificador 0x13ac8f04 ... ¿A qué menú se refiere? no puedes saberlo salvo que tu hayas proporcionado los identificadores.

Comment: gracias y para crear archivos  script solo los guardo como .rc? no necesito compilarlos de alguna manera especial? y para incluirlos?